# Android ADB connect to Fuhu Nabi 2 on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, usb, adb

Any details on how to connect with non-root Fuhu Nabi 2 to Android ADB on Windows 7? Rooting is not an option. USB Debugging is enabled on Tablet.

I installed Android Composite USB Interface(android_winusb.inf) with the following mods under

```
    [Google.NTx86] and 
    [Google.NTamd64]
    ;Fuhu Nabi 2
    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7000
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7100&MI_01
```

I know machine ADB works because I can connect to ASUS TF300T successfully. And ADB with Nabi 2 works on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

I need the answer to this as well. I can't figure out a way to get a Nabi 2 connected for ADB either despite being able to connect a Nexus 7 just fine. There are also no drivers on the (admittedly very small and poor) Fuhu Nabi website.